# Why does this sprite scale?

Tags: actionscript-3

Here's a very simple AS3 project consisting of one class which draws a rectangle. When I run it, the rectangle is clearly larger than 100x100 pixels.  After pulling out my hair for a few hours I thought I'd ask: why?

Edit: I know that it isn't correct because, though I have my screen resolution set to 1280x800, if I set the width to 500 it takes up almost all of my screen.

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Draw extends Sprite
{
    private var screen:Sprite;

    public function Draw():void 
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageHandler);
    }

    private function stageHandler(e:Event):void{
        screen = new Sprite();
        screen.graphics.clear();
        screen.graphics.beginFill(0x333333,.9);
        screen.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100, 100);

        screen.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(screen);
        trace(stage.width + "," + stage.height); 
    }
}
}
```

:

[image: Screenshot of 500x500, with my full screen width of 1280 behind]

Comment: It shows up as 100x100 for me when I run your code in a new SWF ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RUV51.png))... how large does your sprite scale to?

Comment: Hi - see my edit, above. If I set it to 500x500 it takes up almost all of my screen. Its width is closer to 1000. I'm running it in Flash Builder. Thanks, David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow your scalemode settigns for your flash player are set in a strange mode from FlashBuilder.

Try setting

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

in your stageHandler function. You code has no errors. The problem is in your publish preview settings somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, thanks. I don't know whether to be angry at myself for forgetting, or at Flash for requiring such an obvious setting.